# Filter Array from Get Items step on lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I am having trouble with this filter array step...

@equals(triggerBody()?['Item_x0020_Received']?['Value'], item()?['Item_x0020_Received']?['Value'])

which comes from a Get Item step. The table that feeds this filter has 3 items in it and after the filter, I still seem to have 3 items (evidenced by the final update item step).

The trigger body is the information from the 'When item created or updated' and the item() is from the 'Get Items' function. Do I have that correct or backwards? I can't figure out what goes where. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the filter designed function? What do you want to compare?

Answer (score 0):

Please share us with more information about your flow and final goal so we can find a proper filter array for you. You can first try with the basic mode of filter array with more introductions on UI to build.